# Stream Raspberry Pi Camera to Internet

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I've surfed the internet for quite a while now for my project but all I could find is projects where people stream the raspberry pi camera to local host. I would like to stream it to the internet and be able to view it from anywhere in the world. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use this tutorial to set up the camera: https://hackernoon.com/spy-your-pet-with-a-raspberry-pi-camera-server-e71bb74f79ea
2. Set stream_localhost off in /etc/motion/motion.conf
3. Forward the port 8081 on your router.
4. Get your IP: https://www.whatismyip.com/
5. Access the webcontrol through :8081

Attention: You need a static IP or dyndns!